# A new convolution, on function of $\mathbb F_p^n$ to $\mathbb F_p$ still zero?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ integer prime, $f$ a function of $A=\mathbb F_p^n$ to $\mathbb F_p$, with $n\geq p+1$.

Is it true that :  for all $x\in A, \sum\limits_{\sigma \in S_n} s(\sigma) \times f(x_\sigma) =0$?

$s$ the signature

$S_n$ is the group of all bijection of $U_n=\{1,...,n\}$ to $U_n$.

If $x=(x_1,...x_n)$ then $x_\sigma=(x_{\sigma(1)},...,x_{\sigma(n)})$.

> The answer is yes, if $p=2$ but what about the other case?

Comment: This is true if $n \geq p^2 - p +1$, but not for $n\leq p^2-p$.

Comment: Why?..............

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see that $s$ is the signature. Then it is true for $n \geq p+1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as $n \geq p+1$, two of the entries of $x$ must be the same by the pigeonhole principle. Let $\tau$ be a transposition fixing those two entries. Then $s(\sigma \circ \tau) = -s(\sigma)$ but $x_{\sigma \circ \tau} = x_\sigma$ so $f(x_{\sigma \circ \tau} ) =f(x_\sigma)$. Thus the terms in your sum for $\sigma$ and $\sigma \circ \tau$ cancel.

Since ${}\circ \tau$ acts on $S_n$ with $n!/2$ orbits of size 2, we can divide the sum into $n!/2$ pairs of terms which cancel, so the whole sum vanishes.